# Getting CLSID for a DLL file?

Tags: windows, com, dll, clsid

I want to create a small app to add and remove user defined context menu entries from the registry. To make this, somehow I need to get the CLSID of an arbitrary DLL so I can back up previous entries if they exist before writing new ones.

Although `regsrv32` somehow manages to create this magical number, I didn't find any way to get that number myself.

I hope there is something better than this:

1. scanning registry for the DLL name
2. if not found, register it, scan again, and then unregister it again

If the DLL has been renamed, I can see a possibility for problems.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider calling [LoadTypeLibEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56a7f9e1-810b-4a42-aa4d-691f4304f5ef(VS.85)) on the DLL specifying REGKIND_NONE and then examine get the [TypeLibInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa713297(VS.71).aspx) information available via the [ITypeLib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1e5d71f-6a4e-45f3-811d-f57024f81a55(VS.85)) interface passed back to you.

There's some information about this sort of thing on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985086.aspx). It's an old VB6-focused link but has useful information about inspecting COM components in this way.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [RegOverridePredefKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724901%28VS.85%29.aspx) to intercept what regsvr32 does to the registry - call RegOverridePredefKey(), then reproduce what regsvr32 does - LoadLibrary() the COM server, call DllRegisterServer() - then inspect the changes done. With RegOverridePredefKey() you will isolate the changes and not let them become persistent.